# Generate S3 URL to fetch image in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In our project we have configured Amazon webservice. On Android application side its required to generate s3 url to get image from server. By using below code, I am trying fetch image but each time I am facing Signature failed or any other exception.

```
 //Set the google token in map
            Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
            logins.put(AppConstants.GOOGLE_CONSTANT, token);

            //Initialize amazon cognito credentials provider
            CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    activity, // Context
                    AppConstants.IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // Identity Pool ID
                    Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
            );

            //Set the google credentials
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider); 

java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
long msec = expiration.getTime();
msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour.
expiration.setTime(msec);

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
          new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); // Default.
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

URL s = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Here when I try to load receiving URL in browser, it's throwing a Signature error.

The issue is, all of the help is for Java. I didn't find any specific help for Android.

I have referred following site
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generating-amazon-s3-pre-signed-urls-with-sse-kms-part-2/
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for getting a pre-signed get url.

```
URL presignedUrl = s3.generatePresignedUrl(
             bucketName, key, new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60));
System.out.println(presignedUrl.toExternalForm());

HttpURLConnection connection = connectToPresignedUrl(
             s3, new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, key));
assertEquals(200, connection.getResponseCode());
```